# Impesonate user account with alternative UPN suffix

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation, winlogon, upn

We have a domain **boo.com** and also somebody defined an alternative UPN suffix **bc**. There is an account created as foo @bc. I need to impersonate that account to connect to SQL Server.

This is what I do:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, 
                                    String lpszDomain,
                                    String lpszPassword, 
                                    int dwLogonType,
                                    int dwLogonProvider, 
                                    ref IntPtr phToken);

LogonUser( 
    "foo",//foo@bc
    "boo.com",//"@bc"
     "Password",
     (int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,//(int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE,//(int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,//(int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,//
     (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,//(int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50,//
     ref m_Token);
...
```

Impersonation seems to work- LogonUser(...) succeeds, but my script doesn't have proper access. Depending on combination of parameters I get either

> System.IO.FileLoadException:File name: 'System.Data, ...

In Sysinternals Process Monitor I can see **"BAD IMPERSONATION"** error.

or, if I play with LogonType and LogonProvider

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.'

Is there any way to impersonate an AD account that defined with alternative UPN suffix?

Oh and if I run from under "foo" account everything works, meaning foo has all the access it needs. Unfortunately I need to run from another service account.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, this is what worked for me:

```
LogonUser( 
"foo@bc",//username with suffix
 NULL,   //domain
 "Password",
 (int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, //logon type
 (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
 ref m_Token);

Console.WriteLine("Current user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
//John Doe - person running the app

WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(m_Token);
identity.Impersonate();

Console.WriteLine("Current user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
//still John Doe!! NOT foo@bc

//database access successful (Integrated Security)
```

surprisingly

> WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

returns account name running the app before and after the impersonation. But access to database is granted anyway.